If $\frac{\text{ED}}{\text{DA}}= \frac{a}{b}$, where $a$ and $b$ are coprime integers and $\gcd(a, b) = 1$, find the value of $a+b$.
Given a triangle $\triangle \text{ABC}$ with side lengths  $\text{AB} = 15$, $\text{BC} = 16$, $\text{CA} = 17$, and the circumcircle $w$. Point $\text{D}$ is located on side $\text{BC}$ such that $\dfrac{\text{BD}}{\text{BC}}= \left(\dfrac{\text{AB}}{\text{AC}}\right)^2$. The extension of $\text{AD}$ intersects $w$ at point $\text{E}$, where $\text{E} \neq \text{A}$. If $\dfrac{\text{ED}}{\text{DA}}= \dfrac{a}{b}$, where $a$ and $b$ are coprime integers and $\gcd(a, b) = 1$, find the value of $a+b$.
I tried drawing and solving it a little, maybe someone can correct me?

Let us label a few things first. Let $AB=c, BC=a, AC=b, AD=d, BD=n, CD=m$ and $DE=e$. With these labellings, we are given that $c=15, a=16, b=17, m+n=a$ and $$\frac{n}{a}=\frac{c^2}{b^2}\ (*)$$ We want to solve for $e/d$.
Now using Stewert's theorem, we have that $$c^2m+b^2n=a(d^2+mn)$$ Then using $(*)$, we have $b^2n=ac^2$ implying that $$c^2m+c^2a=a(d^2+mn)\Rightarrow c^2(a+m)=a(d^2+mn)$$ Solving for $d^2$, we get $$d^2=\frac{c^2(a+m)}{a}-mn=\frac{c^2(a+m)-amn}{a}$$
Now using the fact that if two chords $BC$ and $AE$ intersect at $D$, then $$AD\cdot DE=BD\cdot CD$$ we get $$de=nm\Rightarrow \frac{e}{d}=\frac{mn}{d^2}=\frac{amn}{c^2(a+m)-amn}$$
Now one can plug in the relations $m=a-n$ and $n=ac^2/b^2$ to finally get $$\frac{e}{d}=\frac{a^2(b^2-c^2)}{b^2(2b^2-c^2)-a^2(b^2-c^2)}$$
Pluggin in values, we get $$\frac{e}{d}=\frac{16384}{85633}$$ The required value then is $16384+85633=102017$.
